# How to call method when user enters specific area on Google Maps

Tags: android, firebase, location

I'm a kind of beginner in programming. I'm creating an Android game in Java with Firebase Database, something like "hide and seek" using Google Maps. First team creates hints (text or photos) and the second team use these hints to find the first team. Every user has his own phone.

The thing I'm struggling with is: when first team user creates a hint, eg. snaps a photo, I want to create an area on the map with the user location as center and a 50m radius. 
When user from the other team enters this area, the proper method is called and he receives the next hint from database.

I've tried doing it using GeoFences and managed to create a geofence and draw a circle on the map (just for checking if it's working). Now, I can't figure out how to set some listener on the second team players devices to listen if they enter this geofence. When they do, I need to call a method which downloades the hint from database.

The code of created geofence:

```
private static final long GEO_DURATION = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "GeofenceIDe";
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 50;
private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;

private void startGeofence() {
    latLng = new LatLng(52.337506, 20.419784);
    Geofence geofence = createGeofence(latLng);
    GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
    addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
}

private Geofence createGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
            .setCircularRegion( latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
            .setExpirationDuration( GEO_DURATION )
            .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            .build();
}

private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
            .addGeofence( geofence )
            .build();
}

private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent( this, GameSummaryActivity.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(
            this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
}

private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            request,
            createGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
        drawGeofence();
    }
}

private Circle geoFenceLimits;
private void drawGeofence() {
    if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
        geoFenceLimits.remove();
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center( latLng)
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
            .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
            .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
    geoFenceLimits = mMap.addCircle( circleOptions );
}***
```

I'm calling "GameSummaryActivity" in Intent just for checking if it's going to work. My goal is to call a method, not an activity.

Any ideas how it can be achieved? Thanks in advance!